Difference between ReentrantLock and synchronized
What is the difference between ReentrantLock and synchronized in Java, and when should I prefer one over the other?
I’ve come across both synchronized blocks and the ReentrantLock class for thread synchronization in Java. While I understand that both can be used to control access to shared resources, I’m unclear about:
The specific differences between the two.
When one should be preferred over the other.
Any performance implications.
Can someone clarify these points with examples?

first (big) difference: synchronized is a keyword (part of the language, JLS 8.4.3.6. synchronized Methods and JLS 14.19. The synchronized Statement); ReentrantLock is a class (part of the API, javadoc)

how is this question related to [tag:screen] and [tag:boot]?

In Java 21, 22, and 23, lengthy use of synchronized with virtual threads would result in pinning. In such cases, synchronized could be replaced easily with a ReentrantLock to avoid pinning. The pinning issue goes away in Java 24+.

ReentrantLock & synchronized are both used for thread synchronization in Java, but they differ in control and features.synchronized is simpler,implicit,and sufficient for straightforward locking with modern JVM optimizations making it performant in low-contention scenarios. In contrast, ReentrantLock provides advanced capabilities like fairness,interruptible locking, non-blocking attempts (tryLock()),and multiple condition variables,making it ideal for high-contention or complex synchronization needs.Use synchronized for simplicity & ReentrantLock for fine-grained control and advanced features
